# Scala JsoupBrowser set UserAgent

Tags: scala

I'm using the scala-scraper library for web scraping. I want to create a `List[JSoupBrowser]` that contains a list of `JsoupBrowsers` with unique user agents. Currently, I have the following code,

```
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.{JsoupBrowser => JSB}
class Scraper() {

  def userAgents : List[String] =
    List (
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Pixel C Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Safari/537.36"
      )


  def browsers : List[JSB] = userAgents.foreach(agent => JSB(agent)) // throws err
  // def browsers: List[JSB] = userAgents.foreach(agent => JSB()) // no err
}
```

However, this is throwing the error

`Cannot resolve reference JSoupBrowser with such signature`

Looking at the [scala-scraper JSoupBrowser source](https://github.com/ruippeixotog/scala-scraper/blob/37bd58e3b67c40131439255ff732d81262e469c5/core/src/main/scala/net/ruippeixotog/scalascraper/browser/JsoupBrowser.scala)
revealed that the class declaration is

`class JsoupBrowser(val userAgent: String = "jsoup/1.8", val proxy: java.net.Proxy = null) extends Browser`

I'm new to Scala so maybe this is just a misunderstanding of constructors.

Why does the first throw an error when a parameter with the correct type is provided to the optional parameter `userAgent` and the default constructor works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `JSB` is an import alias for `JsoupBrowser`:

```
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.{JsoupBrowser => JSB}
```

`JSB()` is legal because it is a call to the [`apply`](https://github.com/ruippeixotog/scala-scraper/blob/37bd58e3b67c40131439255ff732d81262e469c5/core/src/main/scala/net/ruippeixotog/scalascraper/browser/JsoupBrowser.scala#L89) method in `JsoupBrowser`'s companion object. As you can see from the linked source code, this `apply` method simply invokes `new JsoupBrowser()`. Basically it's a convenient method to create an instance of `JsoupBrowser` with the default parameters.

As you figured out, if you want to override the default `userAgent` parameter, you have to use the `new` keyword to instantiate a `JsoupBrowser`. You're incorrect, however, in surmising that this is solely due to the fact that `JsoupBrowser` is a class. The reason you must use `new` is because there aren't any overloaded versions of `apply` in `JsoupBrowser`'s companion object that allow you to override the default parameters. An example of this would be:

```
object JsoupBrowser {
  ...
  def apply(agent: String): Browser = new JsoupBrowser(userAgent = agent)
  ...
}
```

Because the above version of `apply` is not available, you cannot call `JSB(agent)` and you must use `new JSB(agent)`.

Also, a more straightforward way to create a `List[JSB]` is:

```
def browsers: List[JSB] = userAgents.map(new JSB(_))
```

Comment: I was ready to accept my answer but yours is much better. Thank you!